# No puedo filtrar los select

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un problema para filtrar los select, lo que quiero hacer es que al selecionar una Marca en el otro select me aparezca su respectivo Modelo.
Como puedo hacerlo?

***Marcas:***

```
 Marcas:[
    {"id":1,"marca":"Acura","logo":"logo_acura.png"},
    {"id":2,"marca":"Aleko","logo":"logo_aleko.png"},
    {"id":3,"marca":"Alfa Romeo","logo":"logo_alfa_romeo.png"}, 
    {"id":4,"marca":"Audi","logo":"audi.png"}, 
    {"id":5,"marca":"BMW","logo":"bmw.png"}, 
    {"id":6,"marca":"Chery","logo":"chery.png"}, 
    {"id":7,"marca":"Chevrolet","logo":"logo_chevrolet.png"}, 
    {"id":8,"marca":"Chrysler","logo":"logo_chrysler.png"}, 
    {"id":9,"marca":"Citroen","logo":"citroen.png"}, 
    {"id":10,"marca":"Daewoo","logo":"logo_daewoo.png"}, 
    {"id":11,"marca":"Dodge","logo":"logo_dodge.png"}, 
    {"id":12,"marca":"Fiat","logo":"fiat.png"}, 
    {"id":13,"marca":"Ford","logo":"ford.png"}, 
    {"id":14,"marca":"Honda","logo":"logo_honda.png"}, 
    {"id":15,"marca":"Hyundai","logo":"logo_hyundai.png"}, 
    {"id":16,"marca":"Iveco","logo":"logo_iveco.png"}, 
    {"id":17,"marca":"Jeep","logo":"logo_jeep.png"}, 
    {"id":18,"marca":"KIA","logo":"logo_kia.png"}, 
    {"id":19,"marca":"Land-Rover","logo":"logo_land_rover.png"}, 
    {"id":20,"marca":"Mercedes-Benz","logo":"mb.png"}, 
    {"id":21,"marca":"Mini","logo":"logo_mini.png"}, 
    {"id":22,"marca":"Mitsubishi","logo":"logo_mitsubishi.png"}, 
    {"id":23,"marca":"Nissan","logo":"logo_nissan.png"}, 
    {"id":24,"marca":"Peugeot","logo":"peugeot.png"}, 
    {"id":25,"marca":"Porsche","logo":"logo_porsche.png"}, 
    {"id":26,"marca":"Renault","logo":"renault.png"}, 
    {"id":27,"marca":"Seat","logo":"logo_seat.png"}, 
    {"id":28,"marca":"Smart","logo":"logo_smart.png"}, 
    {"id":29,"marca":"Subaru","logo":"logo_subaru.png"}, 
    {"id":30,"marca":"Toyota","logo":"toyota.png"}, 
    {"id":31,"marca":"Volkswagen","logo":"logo_volkswagen.png"}, 
    {"id":32,"marca":"Suzuki","logo":"logo_suzuki.png"}, 
    {"id":33,"marca":"Volvo","logo":"logo_volvo.png"}
]
```

***Modelos:***

```
Modelos: [
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"400Adventure","modelo_id":1,"variante_id":1},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Agile Dinamyc","modelo_id":2,"variante_id":2},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Astra Attractive","modelo_id":3,"variante_id":3},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Astra GSI Sdl","modelo_id":4,"variante_id":4},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Astra li Fire Way","modelo_id":5,"variante_id":5},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Aveo Confort","modelo_id":6,"variante_id":6},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Blazer Attractive","modelo_id":7,"variante_id":7},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"C-10 Sport","modelo_id":8,"variante_id":8},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Camaro Essence","modelo_id":9,"variante_id":9},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Captiva Precision","modelo_id":10,"variante_id":10}, 
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Celta Drive Pack Conectividad","modelo_id":11,"variante_id":11}, 
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"2141 variante 1","modelo_id":278,"variante_id":12},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Legend variante 2","modelo_id":279,"variante_id":13},
    {"modelo_mas_variante":"Integra variante x","modelo_id":280,"variante_id":14}
]
```

***CODIGO:***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Navbr from "../navbar/Navbr";
import Footer from "../footer/Footer";

import "./filter.css";
import { Dropdown, DropdownButton } from "react-bootstrap";

const baseUrl = "http://periplo-cars.test";

function Filter() {
    const [marca, setMarca] = useState([]);
    const [modelo, setModelo] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const traerMarcas = async () => {
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/filtro/marcas`;
            const result = await axios.get(url);
            /*      console.log(result.data); */

            setMarca(result.data);
        };
        traerMarcas();
    }, []);
    /*  console.log(marca); */

    useEffect(() => {
        const traerModelos = async () => {
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/filtro/modelos`;
            const result = await axios.get(url);
            /*       console.log(result.data);  */

            setModelo(result.data);
        };
        traerModelos();
    }, []);
    /* console.log(modelo); */

    /*     const [selectedIdMarca, setSelectedIdMarca] = useState([]);  
    const [selectedIdModelo, setSelectedIdModelo] = useState(undefined);
   
   
 const handleMarca =(e) =>{
   const getMarcaData= e.target.value
  

    const getModeloData = modelo.find(modelo=>modelo.modelo_id === getMarcaData).modelo
    setModelo(getModeloData)
  

 }
 const handleModelo = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setSelectedIdModelo(e.target.value);
  }; */

    const getMarca = [...new Set(marca.map((item) => item.id))];
    getMarca.sort();
    /*  console.log(getMarca)
 console.log(marca) */

    const handleMarca = (e) => {
        let modelos = modelo.filter((modelo) => modelo.id === e.target.value);
        modelos = [...new Set(modelo.map((item) => item.modelo_id))];
        modelos.sort();
        console.log(modelos);
        setModelo(modelos);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className=" imgheader">
                <Navbr />
                <div className="filter">
                    <div class="form">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="text"
                            autocomplete="off"
                            required
                        />
                        <label class="label-name">
                            <span
                                class="content-name"
                                style={{ color: "#fff" }}
                            >
                                Buscar Auto
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="dropdown">
                    <select
                        name="marca"
                        id="getMarca"
                        onChange={(e) => handleMarca(e)}
                    >
                        <option value="0">Marca</option>
                        {marca.map((car, i) => {
                            return (
                                <option key={i} value={marca}>
                                    {car.marca}
                                </option>
                            );
                        })}
                    </select>

                    <select
                        name="modelo"
                        id="getModelo"
                        onChange={(e) => handleModelo(e)}
                    >
                        <option value="0">Modelo</option>
                        {modelo.map((car, i) => {
                            return (
                                <option key={i} value={car.modelo_id}>
                                    {car.modelo_mas_variante}
                                </option>
                            );
                        })}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Filter;

if (document.getElementById("filtro")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Filter />, document.getElementById("filtro"));
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema? dices tener un problema pero en ningun momento mencionas que problema es, que errores te surgen? esta pregunta le faltan detalles. Lee [ask]

Comment: Disculpa si no se entendió bien pero a lo que voy es que  no se como filtrar los select, para que  al colocar la marca me traiga el modelo.

Comment: el campo variante_id corresponderia al id de la marca?

Comment: seria modelo_id corresponde al id del modelo y id corresponde al de marca

Comment: @juanarede al parecer no se entendió mi pregunta. Como sabes que si elijo por ejemplo Nissan, me filtre por los modelos correspondientes? que campo usas para filtrar eso?

Answer (score 0):

La solucion podria ser en el handler en lugar de modelo.id usar modelo.modelo_id

```
        let modelos = modelo.filter((modelo) => modelo.modelo_id=== e.target.value);
        modelos = [...new Set(modelo.map((item) => item.modelo_id))];
        modelos.sort();
        console.log(modelos);
        setModelo(modelos);
    };
```

Y en el select usar car.id en lugar de marca.

Comment: Edson Probé y no me funcionó

Comment: Puedes eliminar esta linea y probar ---> modelos = [...new Set(modelo.map((item) => item.modelo_id))];

Comment: probé borrandolo, y al hacer click me tira un array vacío

Comment: emule el codigo que te digo en javascript puro y me funciono, fijate que valor esta llegando al event.target.value imprimiendolo en consola